# Deploy helm on master node with taints labels

Tags: kubernetes, devops, release, kubernetes-helm

Hi I am trying to initialize helm tiller on master node.

Master node is:

```
Name:               ip-10-3-196-251.ec2.internal
Roles:              master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=m4.xlarge
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1a
                    kubernetes.io/role=master
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/taints=[{"key":"dedicated","value":"master","effect":"NoSchedule"}]
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
CreationTimestamp:  Mon, 01 Jun 2020 12:50:53 +0200
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false

...
...
...
```

I am running this:

```
helm init \
    --history-max=1000 \
    --service-account tiller \
    --node-selectors "kubernetes.io/role=master" \
    --override spec.template.spec.tolerations[0].key=node-role.kubernetes.io/master \
    --override spec.template.spec.tolerations[0].effect=NoSchedule \
    --skip-refresh \
    --upgrade
```

But when I describe the pod i am getting still

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                From                Message
  ----     ------             ----               ----                -------
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  1m (x86 over 16m)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 9 node(s) didn't match node selector
  Warning  FailedScheduling   1m (x57 over 17m)  default-scheduler   0/11 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu, 3 PodToleratesNodeTaints, 8 MatchNodeSelector.e
```

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: If this is a new setup and a new cluster, is there any reason to not use Helm 3 (which doesn't have Tiller)?

Comment: Yes, We have our own software implemented in Golang which uses, Helm libraries for v2. We will migrate to v3 but it is not easy atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Master node has taint `node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true:NoSchedule` but you have given `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule` in the command.

Use below command

```
helm init \
    --history-max=1000 \
    --service-account tiller \
    --node-selectors "kubernetes.io/role=master" \
    --override spec.template.spec.tolerations[0].key=node-role.kubernetes.io/master \
    --override spec.template.spec.tolerations[0].operator=Equal \
    --override spec.template.spec.tolerations[0].value=true \
    --override spec.template.spec.tolerations[0].effect=NoSchedule \
    --skip-refresh \
    --upgrade
```

Comment: Should I use just `node-role.kubernetes.io/master`? When I add =true, it returns an error to me with unexpected value. I will check it tomorrow, because people are releasing charts to the cluster today.

Comment: @DanielHornik did you had time to check it?